# using sublime text 2. When I renamed file/folder in sidebar ,file/folder is overwritten WITHOUT confirming

Tags: sublimetext2, alert, rename, setting

I use sublime text2. When I renamed fileA to fileB that already exist,
the file is over written without confirming.
like this case. http://www.sublimetext.userecho.com/topic/116014-folder-renaming-bug/

Does anyone know how to change setting to check whether the file exist or not?

Comment: I've just lot several hours of work because I'm working on a local copy and the overwritten files aren't moved to OS X's trash. gg.